# Sockets and Objects in Java very basic example

Tags: java, sockets, object

I am trying to create a simple transfer between one Server and one Client. I am trying to send an Object from client to server. I have checked my code so many times really I really don't know why t doesn't work. Also, id like to add that I have created two separate projects in netbeans, one for client and one for server. The code is the following:

Client:

```
package client;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.Serializable;

class Object implements Serializable {  
    String one;
    String two;

    public Object(String one, String two){
        this.one = one;
        this.two = two;
    } 

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "\nOne: " + one +"\nTwo: " + two;
    }            

}


public class Client {  

    public static void main(String[] args){    

        try {
            Object obj= new Object ("Something", "Else");

            Socket sock = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 1111);

            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream());  
            System.out.println("Connecting to "+ sock.getInetAddress()+ " and port "+sock.getPort());

            System.out.println("Local Address :"+sock.getLocalAddress()+" Port:"+sock.getLocalPort());

            oos.writeObject(obj);
            oos.flush();
            oos.close();
            sock.close();
            System.out.println("Connection Closing...");

        } catch (Exception ex){
            System.out.println("No Conenction");
        } 
    } 
}
```

Server:

```
<!-- language: lang-java -->


package server;

import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;


class Object implements Serializable {  
    String one;
    String two;

    public Object(String one, String two){
        this.one = one;
        this.two = two;
    } 

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "\nOne: " + one +"\nTwo: " + two;
    }            

}

public class Server {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        try{
            ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(1111,10);

            System.out.println("Waiting Incoming Connection...");

            System.out.println("Local Address :"+server.getInetAddress()+" Port:"+server.getLocalPort());

            Socket sock = server.accept();
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(sock.getInputStream());               

            Object ob=new Object ("Once", "Upon"); //for test
            Object obj2= null;
            try{
                obj2 = (Object )ois.readObject();
                System.out.println(obj2);

            }catch (Exception ex){
                 System.out.println("nothing...");
            }
            System.out.println(ob); 
            ois.close();

        }catch (Exception ex){
            System.out.println("Error during I/O");
            ex.getMessage();
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } 
    } 
}
```

The code works, but the object is never sent =/ . I am getting the message "nothing.." thatis in the exception. The connection works because with simple messages BufferedReader() , BufferedWritter() they exchange messages. The problem is with objects ....

Comment: Please consider cleaning up your code sample.

Comment: When you get an exception don't just print 'nothing', or nothing. ***Never*** do that. Print the *exception.* Then you will know what's going wrong. You may not have even had to ask this question if you had paid proper attention to this.

Answer (score 6):

1) Don't just say "some exception is thrown". Print which exception is thrown, and where (`e.printStackTrace()`).

2) Most probably, you must use the same class in both server and client. That means the same package, too (`client.Object`) is not the same that (`server.Object`). Probably you are getting a `ClassCastException`).

3) Please don't name your classes with the names of classes from the API, and less than any from `java.lang`. **Any name** is better than `Object`.

UPDATE: a few implementation tips

Quick and dirty. Rename your `server.Object` to `server.MyServer`. Import `client.Object`. Make the `obj2` variable a `client.Object`. The trouble is that to run your server you will need your client code in the classpath.

More elaborated. Create a third class (say `mytest.Bean`) with the definition of the object you want to transmit. Use such class in both client and server code (don't forget to add it to the classpath).

In the end, when you have a real application, you will make the shared data a library, and import it both in the server and client applications.

Comment: +1. The OP needs 3 projects: 1 for the client, 1 for the server, and 1 for the classes shared by both, and whose instances are exchanged through the network

Comment: @JBNizet could you please explain me how to do this ? I have wasted 2 days here, am I supposed to create a new project for the class "object" ? how can I link it to the other two projects ? thanks !

Comment: Yes, and this class should really be renamed. Create a new project, produce a jar from its compiled classes, and add this jar to the classpath of the client and server projects.

Comment: @SJuan76 this is the error: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to server.Object

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks, I am using NetBeans , how can I produce and add that jar to the class path? is there a step by step , something ? I really have no idea :S

Comment: I expected `client.Object cannot be cast to server.Object`. You are receiving a String instead of the original object. Print it to know what is happenning.

Comment: I don't have any idea either. I tend to not rely on IDEs to compile classes and produce jar files, but on build tools like Gradle, Ant, or even (gasp!) Maven. And NetBeans is not my IDE, but I'm sure it's possible to generate a jar from a NetBeans project. Search the menus.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than creating a project for each class, put all of your classes into the same project.

In fact, the easiest way to do this is probably to use one class. Rename your `Object` class to something more meaningful (how about `MyNetworkType`?). `MyNetworkType` should have a `main` method which accepts 'client' or 'server' as command-line parameters. If you get 'client', run a `client` method which contains the code in the `Client.main()` you gave. If you get 'server', run a method which contains the code in the `Server.main()` you gave.

Your class will end up looking something like this:

```
class MyNetworkType implements Serializable {

    //
    // Data here
    //

    public MyNetworkType() {
        // initialize your data
    }

    public static void runClient() {
        // Copy the code from Client.main() here
    }

    public static void runServer() {
        // Copy the code from Server.main() here
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if( args[0].equals("client") ) {
            MyNetworkType.runClient();
        }
        else if( args[0].equals("server") ){
            MyNetworkType.runServer();
        }
    }
}
```

I know how to pass command-line parameters in eclipse (and on the command-line, of course), but for figuring it out with NetBeans you're on your own.

Note that this isn't good design. In practice you'll definitely want your Client and Server in separate classes (but you don't necessarily need to put them in separate projects). But you're looking for a very basic example, and what could be simpler than a single class?

I hope this helps.